# Remove Nuget Package Completely from System

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package, bin

I have installed a nuget package which copies some structures for validation.
To test something I modified the contents of the structure from the nuget directory.
I have reinstalling it to get the original structures back but I am not able to do it.
Things which I have tried :

- Uninstalled and installed package from command line
- Deleted complete .nuget directory from the system and then ran dotnet restore command

Still its installing with the changed structures. How to completely remove it ?

Comment: What do you mean by NuGet structures? What’s the source of this package? Did you replace the package at the source? It would be good to check the GlobalPaclagesFolder (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/Consume-Packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders)

If the package feed is a http feed, it may be good to clear the http-cache before trying. Check out “NuGet locals” command and then use clear.

Comment: @AnandGaurav  Its not nuget structures its some json structure which is already there in nuget for its purpose.The source is nuget.org. It tried Nuget locals clean all command too but its of no use in this case

Comment: Have you deleted nuget from `c:\users\xxx\.nuget\` folder as well?

Comment: @LazZiya Yes I have deleted it.